# Android equivalent of UIWebView in Xcode

Tags: android, widget

Coming from an iPhone world...

In Android, I am looking for an iPhone UIWebView-like control which can display HTML and let me catch clicks on links and stop the navigation. My apps display text with commands as href's in the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [`android.webkit.WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for the display, and [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for dealing with clicks on links.